# Contar cantidad de registros SQL en un mismo campo

Tags: sql, postgresql

Es posible contar cuantos registros hay en una consulta, quiero que aparezcan como una columna mas ya que la consulta debe arrojar una sola fila.

```
SELECT dep.nombre as departamento,                   
sum(cap.total_mosquitos) as total_mosquito,
sum(cap.total_anopheles) AS total_anopheles,
sum(cap.casa_positiva)   AS casa_positiva,
sum(cap.casa_inspeccionada) AS casa_inspeccionada,
sum(cap.componente_inspeccionado) AS componenente_inspeccionado,
sum(cap.tiempo_colecta)  AS tiempo_colecta,
count(cap.id_tipo_actividad) AS programa_regular    
FROM pl_captura_anopheles cap
inner join ctl_caserio cas on (cap.id_caserio =cas.id)
inner join ctl_canton can on (cas.id_canton = can.id)
inner join ctl_municipio mun on (can.id_municipio = mun.id)
inner join ctl_departamento dep on (dep.id=mun.id_departamento)
inner join pl_tipo_captura tc   on(cap.id_tipo_captura=tc.id)
inner join ctl_pl_tipo_actividad act   on(cap.id_tipo_actividad=act.id)
where  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cap.fecha)=2018)
group by dep.nombre
```

En el  count quiero saber cuantos hay de tipo de ctl_tipo actividad 1 y cuantos de tipo 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida actual:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: o sea queres agregar dos columnas mas? podrias poner aunque sea un minimo ejemplo de tu salida actual y de la que querrias? y otra cosa, estas agrupando por nombre, entonces no va a salir una sola fila..

Comment: Una sola fila para cada nombre y si quiero agregar dos columnas mas que detallen cuantas hay de cada tipo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agregas las columnas con un case ejemplo:

```
Select (resto de columnas).., SUM(CASE cap.id_tipo_actividad WHEN 1 then 1 else 0 END) as control_foco1, SUM(CASE cap.id_tipo_actividad WHEN 2 then 1 else 0 END) as control_foco2
```

La idea es que la función case retorne el valor 1 cuando es el resultado esperado de manera que se pueda sumar con la función SUM, si no es el valor esperado se deja en 0 para que no afecte la suma.

NOTA: verificar la sintaxis de la cláusula case ya que lo hice al vuelo.

Saludos.

Comment: me ganaste de mano ;) esta es la solucion.

Comment: Me ha servido mucho, la adapte asi: sum(CASE cap.id_tipo_actividad  WHEN 2 then 1 else 0 END) as control_foco

Comment: Edito ya que así es que debe ser, que bueno que te sirvió cuando la edite por favor marcala como respuesta aceptada. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la cláusula **Compute By**, pero esta te da el resultado en otro set de datos en lugar de agregarlo como una fila que es lo que deseas. Para lograr esto, utiliza un Union all quitando la columna por la que haces el group by

```
SELECT dep.nombre as departamento,                   
sum(cap.total_mosquitos) as total_mosquito,
sum(cap.total_anopheles) AS total_anopheles,
sum(cap.casa_positiva)   AS casa_positiva,
sum(cap.casa_inspeccionada) AS casa_inspeccionada,
sum(cap.componente_inspeccionado) AS componenente_inspeccionado,
sum(cap.tiempo_colecta)  AS tiempo_colecta,
count(cap.id_tipo_actividad) AS programa_regular    
FROM pl_captura_anopheles cap
inner join ctl_caserio cas on (cap.id_caserio =cas.id)
inner join ctl_canton can on (cas.id_canton = can.id)
inner join ctl_municipio mun on (can.id_municipio = mun.id)
inner join ctl_departamento dep on (dep.id=mun.id_departamento)
inner join pl_tipo_captura tc   on(cap.id_tipo_captura=tc.id)
inner join ctl_pl_tipo_actividad act   on(cap.id_tipo_actividad=act.id)
where  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cap.fecha)=2018)
group by dep.nombre

union all

SELECT 'Totales',              
sum(cap.total_mosquitos) as total_mosquito,
sum(cap.total_anopheles) AS total_anopheles,
sum(cap.casa_positiva)   AS casa_positiva,
sum(cap.casa_inspeccionada) AS casa_inspeccionada,
sum(cap.componente_inspeccionado) AS componenente_inspeccionado,
sum(cap.tiempo_colecta)  AS tiempo_colecta,
count(cap.id_tipo_actividad) AS programa_regular    
FROM pl_captura_anopheles cap
inner join ctl_caserio cas on (cap.id_caserio =cas.id)
inner join ctl_canton can on (cas.id_canton = can.id)
inner join ctl_municipio mun on (can.id_municipio = mun.id)
inner join ctl_departamento dep on (dep.id=mun.id_departamento)
inner join pl_tipo_captura tc   on(cap.id_tipo_captura=tc.id)
inner join ctl_pl_tipo_actividad act   on(cap.id_tipo_actividad=act.id)
where  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cap.fecha)=2018)
```

Esa es la idea en general, para llegar a tu requerimiento debes adaptar la parte del segundo select. No me quedó muy claro qué exactamente quieres contar